# VBA Autofilter with Inputbox

Tags: vba

So I am running into a problem with being able to specify numerical values. For example, I want to be able to do > 100 for the filter utilizing the input box. I can only do words like Action, AMERICAS, and etc.

```
Sub Criteria_Region_NewSheet()
   Dim x As Long
   Dim myValue As Variant
   Dim mysheet As Variant

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   mysheet = ActiveSheet.Name

   On Error Resume Next
   y = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("*", Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(20, 3)), 0)
   'Region is the criteria
   x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Sales", Range(Cells(1, y), Cells(100, y)), 0)
   On Error GoTo 0

   myValue = InputBox("Input Region")

   On Error Resume Next
   'Filter
   Range(Cells(x, y), Cells(x, y)).AutoFilter Field:=x, Criteria1:=myValue
   On Error GoTo 0

   'Copies Information
   Range(Cells(x, y), Cells(x, y)).Select
   ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
   Worksheets.Add.Paste

   'Formats columns
   Columns("A:X").EntireColumn.AutoFit
   Range("A1:F100").EntireRow.AutoFit

   ' Unfilter
   Worksheets(mysheet).ShowAllData

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Region", Range(Cells(y, 1), Cells(y, 100)), 0)

Comment: So what happens when you type in ">100"?

Comment: You will get values over 100. However, for this example if you search based on Region you will get blanks.  Also you can type partial words like AMER* to give you results like North America and South America. I actually created a more flexible line of code after.